# Populating React dropdown asyncrhonously with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

### Background

I'm attempting to create a dropdown that retrieves State Codes (AZ, WI, WY, etc.) from a backend API and then populates an on-screen dropdown with the  values.

I have a React component that looks like this (an ellipsis representing code that I'm omitting for clarity):

**Person.jsx**

```
export class Person extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  ...

    this.props.getStateCodes();
  }

  render(){
    ...
    <select
              id="personState"
              name="personState"
              className="form-control dropDownStyle"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.props.person.personState}
            >
                {this.props.stateCodes && this.props.stateCodes.map((option) => (
                        <option key={option.id} value={option.data}>{option.data}</option>
                        ))
                }
            </select>
    ...
  }

}
```

I then have Redux action creators, including an excerpt like this:

**personContract.js**

```
export const actionCreators = {
...
  getStateCodes: () => async (dispatch) => {
    getStateCodesResponse(dispatch);
},
...
export function getStateCodesResponse(dispatch) {
const endpoint = window.location.origin + '/Home/GetStateCodes';
fetch(endpoint, {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
})
    .then(function (response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            const errors = ['Unable to retrieve state codes.'];
            dispatch({ type: "SET_ERROR", errors: errors });
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            return;
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            const stateCodes = data.stateCodes;
            // const stateCodes = result.PayLoad.StateCodes;
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            dispatch({ type: 'STATECODES', stateCodes });
        }
    });
}
...
}
```

Then a reducer that includes:

**Contract.js**

```
const initialState ={
...
stateCodes: [],
...
};
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
...
if (action.type == "STATECODES"){
    const stateCodes = action.stateCodes;
    return {
        ...state,
        errors: [],
        stateCodes: stateCodes
    }
}
...
}
```

### Problem

Initially, I did not include `{this.props.stateCodes &&` in the Person.jsx file. The issue then, was that I'd get an error that `this.props.stateCodes` was not defined. I added in `{this.props.stateCodes &&`, however, now it never runs `this.props.stateCodes.map` at all. It's almost as if I need to `render()` to run again after the State Codes have been retrieved, but I don't know how to accomplish that.

Comment: Just noticed that you are passing dispatch from your action creator.     
   dispatch({ type: 'STATECODES', dispatch, stateCodes }). Remove dispatch from the argument and just send type and payload as stateCodes and give a try.

Comment: No change, but I will update the code in the examples. Good catch!

Comment: How is your "Person" class receiving the "stateCodes" prop? It does not appear to be using redux connect, so how is it receiving those props, when they change as a result of your API call?

Comment: That may very well be the problem. I do see `import { connect } from "react-redux";` at the top of my Person.jsx file, but perhaps I'm missing a piece of plumbing to make it work?

Comment: Based on the posted code, everything looks good. I doubt redux connect code in your component. Your `stateCodes` in redux state's root level, So we need to map state with your root level. Else you can connect as like,
`const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  stateCodes: state.{name defined in your create Store}.stateCodes
});
`